# Substring removes forward slash?

Tags: android, string, substring

```
text = Daily 10 am - 5 pm.\\nClosed Thanksgiving and Christmas.

private String activateNewlines( String text ) {
        String temp = text;
        if ( text.contains( "\\n") ) {
            while ( temp.contains( "\\n" ) ) {
                int index = temp.indexOf( "\\n" );
                temp = temp.substring( 0, index ) + temp.substring( index + 1 );
            }
            return temp;
        }

        return text;
    }
```

I'm trying to get rid of an extra slash for a special character but for some reason substring ends up removing the forward slash. Does substring not like slashes at the beginning of strings? The final string ends up becoming

```
Daily 10 am - 5 pm.nClosed Thanksgiving and Christmas.
```

What I need is

```
Daily 10 am - 5 pm.\nClosed Thanksgiving and Christmas.
```

EDIT: What ended up working for me:

```
    String temp = text;
    if ( text.contains( "\\n") ) {
        temp = temp.replaceAll( "\\\\n", "\\\n" );
        int x = 5;
        return temp;
    }

    return text;
```

This actually allows the TextView to recognize the newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should simply do this,

```
string.replaceAll("\\n", "\n")
```

Detailed code,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String text = "Daily 10 am - 5 pm.\\nClosed Thanksgiving and Christmas.";
    Log.d("TEMP", "*********************************" + activateNewlines(text));

}

private String activateNewlines( String text ) {
    String temp = text;

    return temp.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
}
```

Logcat output is,

```
  08-28 19:16:00.944: D/TEMP(9739): *********************************Daily 10 am - 5 pm.\nClosed Thanksgiving and Christmas.
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but surprisingly after checking the values in the debugger nothing changes.

Comment: I ran it just now. It works fine. I edited source code for you.

Comment: Strangely, I don't know why, replaceAll( "\\n", "\n") is not working for me. What did end up working was an earlier solution (the poster deleted it though), see original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, but here goes. So, `"\n"` is a new line. `"\\n"` is a backslash and an n, `\n`. You can just use replaceAll to get rid of it: `string.replaceAll("\n", "")`. This is where I get confused, I'm not sure what you exactly want. If you want to keep the new line it then you have to properly get it from wherever you're getting it from (e.g. you should get a `\n` character instead of the escaped version.).

Comment: A string in my program contained "\\n" but I wanted to replace those with "\n", hoping that when I set TextView.setText it would recognize the newlines and actually draw the characters on the newline. Replace all doesn't seem to work. I've looked at the value after a temp = replaceAll(...) and nothing is replaced.

Comment: Hmmm Then what @VendettaDroid suggests (`string.replaceAll("\\n", "\n")`) should work. Unless what the string has is actually something else.